# Installing Angular behind proxy

Tags: npm, proxy, npm-install

Angular noob here any help will be much appreciated.

I am trying to install angular on proxy network at my work. Initially npm install -g @angular/cli was giving an error. I fixed that by doing:-

1) npm config set proxy https://proxyaddress portnumber, 
2) https://npm config set https-proxy http://proxyaddress portnumber.

Now when i run npm install -g @angular/cli it says

@angular/cli@8.3.22 postinstall C:\Users\spacemoney\appData\roaming\npm\node_modules\angular\cli\
node./bin/postinstall/script.js

I dont think angular is installed yet because it still says ng is not recognized as internal or external command. What should i do ? How would i Install it. Please help. Thank You !

Comment: If you got few warnings while installing, then you can ignore them for now. Close and reopen the terminal and try `ng` command

Comment: run `npm list -g` and see if `@angular/cli` is listed.

Comment: did that, its not listed  '--(empty)

Comment: Can you post an image of the command window after running `npm install -g @angular/cli`?